# Why does a blurred out background make this photo look like a miniature?

Tags: focus, blur

I have this photo before and after being blurred (From Macphun software ad):
[image: Not Blurred]
[image: Blurred]

I dont know about you but for some reason the blurred version almost makes the island look like it is an intricately created miniature. I am not sure why.

I have seen this effect used in the Game of Thrones intro as well as some games but I cant explain how it works. Why does our brain perceive size differently in these scenarios?

Comment: Hmm... the answer to the duplicate question doesn't make any sense for this image. It talks about how things near the camera are also blurred, but that's not the case her.

Comment: I think you'll find some great answers on this page: https://ask.metafilter.com/88449/Why-does-tiltshift-photography-make-things-look-tiny 

It made for a interesting read!

Comment: @user1118321 - just the fact that the background is blurred also does it.  Generally speaking, if something is as far away as the island, it will be at infinity focus for the lens and the background will not be blurred.  Blurring the background tells our brain that it is much closer to the camera and therefore must be small.

Comment: @user1118321 actually, the blur makes the island seem much closer, and mentally only miniatures can appear so small when so close.